# Displaying Data through div and using show and hide functionalities

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My html file is :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>
            <nav>
                <ul id="leftNavUl">
                    <li><a id="sr" href="#staticRoutingFiledset">Static Routing</a></li>
                    <li><a id="vp" href="#vpn">VPN</a></li>
                    <li><a id="fw" href="#firewall">Firewall</a></li>
                    <li><a id="ip" href="#IPS">IPS</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="features"><fieldset>ABC</fieldset></div>
            <div class="features">A</div>
            <div class="features">B</div>
            <div class="features">C</div> 
        </body> 
    </html>
```

My Css File is

```
.features{
   width: 760px;
   height:370px;        
   margin-bottom: 12px;
   border-color: #000000;
   background-color: #FFFFFF;
   position:absolute;
   top:12px;
   left:140px;
}
ul#leftNavUl {
color:#FFF;
list-style-type:none;
margin-top:41px;
}

ul#leftNavUl li {
background-color:#0357ea;
margin:1px;
width:120px;
}

#leftNav ul#leftNavUl li a {
color:#FFF;
display:block;
width:120px;
height:30px;
text-align:center;
text-decoration:none;
line-height:30px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
}
```

My js file should be able to show and hide in the right side I am creating a menu in the left column and showing coorresponding div in the right column.

Can you tell me whether I am doing it right in the js file:

```
document.getElementById('#vp').onClick()=function(){
    //displaying all the other divs and hiding the overlapping div 
    // somehow its not working please suggest 
}
```

Comment: actually its not required to give '#' in document.getElementById('#vp') , you can give `document.getElementById('vp')`

Comment: `My js file should be able to show and hide in the right side I am creating a menu in the left column and showing coorresponding div in the right column.` feels like you're missing some punctuation here.

Comment: can u post the code u have written for your comments. and on clicking links what divs u want to hide??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. It will take each list item and on click, show the corresponding div and hide the rest.

```
$('#leftNavUl li').click(function(e){
   $('.features').hide().eq($(this).index()).show();
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V4Aqw/1)

Comment: can you please clear what purpose 'e' is serving as argument , I have limited knwoledge of jquerry so please ignore the stupidity.

Comment: @user2865688 `e` is unnecessary here, I added it out of habit.

Answer (score 0):

Trythis

```
<div id="navi">
<ul>
      <li><a class='link1' href="#first">First link</a></li>
      <li><a class='link2' href="#second">Second link</a></li>
      <li><a class='link3' href="#third">Third link</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class='link1' id="content1" style="display:block;">

</div>

<div class='link2' id="content2" style="display:none;">

</div>

<div class='link3' id="content3" style="display:none;">

</div>
```

Script

```
$("#navi a").click(function(){

    $('div[id^="content"]').hide();

    $("div" + "." + $(this).attr('class') ).show();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Kx3Wf/1/)

Answer (score 0):

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/OSOmIMU/1/edit)

**I think this will help you**

In you HTML anchor tag add a [mousedown()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/mousedown) event and call it as below

```
<li><a id="vp" href="#vpn" onmousedown="call()">VPN</a></li>
```

in JS

```
function call(){
    alert('Hai');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
document.getElementById('vp').onclick = function() {
    //displaying all the other divs and hiding the overlapping div 
    // somehow its not working please suggest 
}
```